# Use recursive query to get a set of array in Angular from Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular5

**What I'm using**

- AngularFire
- FireStore
- New AngularFire syntax for Firestore

**What I'm trying to do**

- To make a tree like structure parents and child's
- make a single array having data from Firestore to loop thorough in my HTML.
- Using recursive functionality want to get top parent then its child based on the parent id and the process continues.

**FireStore Collection Structure**

```
{
 "tree": {
    "SBGWONEXBKt6KGQsfSLI": {
      "id": null,
      "name": 'Top Parent',
    },
    "az6WmIkRFoC4pvhoXRK0": {
      "id": "SBGWONEXBKt6KGQsfSLI",
      "name": 'Child A 1',
    },
    "UytpnMpaO0rxGK2avY1J": {
      "id": "SBGWONEXBKt6KGQsfSLI",
      "name": 'Child A 2',
    },
    "hhPZun77qQg4o90bYOT2": {
      "id": "az6WmIkRFoC4pvhoXRK0",
      "name": 'Child B1',
    },
    ...... and so on
 }
}
```

**End Result:**

```
[{
 'name': 'Top Parent',
 'child': [{
           'name': 'Child A 1',
           'child': [{
                      'name': 'Child B1',
                      'child': []
                    }]
          },
          {
            'name': 'Child A 2',
            'child': []
          },
          ...... and so on
          ]
  }]
}]
```